# Mosquitto on Windows with TLS enabled and DH params provided fails

Tags: windows, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I've installed Mosquitto 2.0.12 (and for test 2.0.11, 1.6.13, 1.6.0, 1.5.5) on Windows 10 and on Windows Server 2019. I've generated certificates and set the certfile, keyfile and cafile options in the configuration accordingly, generated DH params and set the dhparamfile option too.

All 2.x and 1.6.x versions fail to start with the error message

```
OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFD4C0DAD30,08): no OPENSSL_Applink
```

In version 1.5.5 the dhparamfile option was not yet supported, so I commented out this option and the broker starts and works properly with TLS.
By accident I forgot to put in the option dhparamfile again when re-running the test with 2.0.12 and now (without dhparamfile) it starts and works too.

Is there any problem known in this area with Mosquitto on Windows? It seems to me that providing these DH parameters is a relevant security feature and on Linux Mosquitto 2.0.12 works without any problem with DH parameters given.

Comment: This looks to be a problem with the version of openssl being used. Did it come with mosquitto or do you install it?

Comment: First, I installed mosquitto on a freshly installed Windows Server 2019 VM. Here, no additional openssl was installed, only the libraries coming with mosquitto have been available.
Later, I tested with an additional openssl installation on that machine and on my regular work laptop with Windows 10 - maybe there is an additional openssl installation, coming with git or xca or whatever, at least I haven't installed it intentionally.